# Datetime 12hrs to 24hrs format in C#

Tags: c#, sql

In C# I have a string in non-military format/12-hrs, like 1:50 pm. I want to convert it into 13:50. How this can be achieved in C# or SQL? I thought of writing a procedure for this problem but am thinking I can find a function in C#.

Simple Varchar columns in sql 1:50 p.m. , 8:46 pm.

Comment: It's not *military* time - it's the time format almost the whole world (except for the US and a few other countries) uses..... please call it **standard** or **24-hour** time .... [Wikipedia on 24-hour time format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Military_time)

Comment: This can probably be done quite easily using DateTime.ParseExact() and DateTime.ToString(), but as @KuyaJohn noted we need better samples to help you.

Comment: *Simple Varchar columns in sql* You do not mean you are *storing* the date/time values in a varchar column - do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with a format string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1:50 PM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm");
```

The default `ToString()` will give you your local representation (which might be AM/PM, too), so you need to use the explicit format string `"HH:mm"` to convert it to 24-hour format. Note that internally, the `DateTime` object doesn't care about AM/PM, this only comes into play when converting to a string, so in your debugger `DateTime` objects might still display as `"1:50 PM"` (depending on your locale).

Answer (score 2):

not sure but try like this

```
DateTime dt;
bool val= DateTime.TryParse("01:00 PM", out dt);
if(val)
dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

if this done work than try with culture option as given in answer by @Botz3000

Comment: Its not. doing it sir. its giving 1:00 pm itself but i want 13:00

Comment: For me it does give `13:00`, but maybe you need a "Parse" with a CultureInfo (see the answer by Botz3000).

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL SERVER 2008, you can try something like

```
SELECT CAST('1:50 pm' AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about only *rapresentation* of the date you already have, you can trick it with different available [DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) inside `C#`.